# Embed photo post from tumblr onto external website

Tags: image, api, photo, tumblr

I'm trying to do and "infinite scroll" gallery onto an external website using tumblr photo posts.

Everything works but I have a big issue.

My foreach function stop working after the first 20 results.
Infinite scroll needs a pagination to work and I need:

1. To retrieve all the post and not just the first 20
2. A way to star counting from the 21th post and then after the 31th to create a pagination

this is the php I'm using with masonry

```
<div id="container">
    <?php
        // tag filtrante
        $tag = 'conceptual';

        $api_key = 'the key';

        // preleva e decodifica il file (prende solo i post di di tipo "photo")
        $tumblr = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/nofrillsintown.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=' . $api_key . '&tag=' . $tag));

        // scorre tutti i post
        foreach ($tumblr->response->posts as $post) {

                // scorre tutte le immagini contenute in un post
                foreach ($post->photos as $photo) {
                        echo '<div class="item"><a href="'.$photo->original_size->url.'" rel="lightbox"><img src="'.$photo->alt_sizes[2]->url.'" /></a></div>';
                };
        };
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `offset` parameter to get posts after the 20th: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

```
$limit = 10;
$page = 1;
$url = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/nofrillsintown.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=' . $api_key. '&tag=' . $tag;
$url .= '&limit=' . $limit. '&offset=' . ($limit * ($page - 1));
```

Since Tumblr only lets you get 20 posts at once, you have to make this call multiple times. You should probably cache the results, rather than doing the call at every page load.